# SQL Query For Customers Not Used For Last 3 Years

Tags: sql, ms-access

I *THINK* I'm having some trouble.

I'm trying to query 2 tables for customers that haven't been used on the table for the last 3 Years. The data consists of data ranging for 7+ years, so customers are used multiple times.

I think the issue with my current query: It's finding data of customers not used in the last 3 years... but it's not accounting for if there is also data of the customer within the last 3 years as well.

Can someone possibly help me? I'm guessing the answer is to use only the data of the customer with the latest date and ignore previous data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tbl_Customer.CustomerID
    , tbl_Customer.CustomerName
    , Table1.ImportDate
    , Table2.ImportDate
FROM 
    tbl_Customer 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table1 ON tbl_Customer.CustomerName = Table1.CustomerName 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 ON tbl_Customer.CustomerName = Table2.CustomerName
WHERE 
    (((DateAdd("yyyy", 3, [Table2].[ImportDate])) < Now()) 
AND 
    ((DateAdd("yyyy", 3, [Table1].[ImportDate])) < Now()))
ORDER BY 
    Table1.ImportDate DESC, 
    Table2.ImportDate DESC;
```

Comment: Awesome, I think I fixed it

`SELECT * FROM
(SELECT tbl_Customer.CustomerID, tbl_Customer.CustomerName, MAX(IIF(SL.ImportDate > GL.ImportDate, SL.ImportDate, GL.ImportDate)) AS [Last Import]
FROM (tbl_Customer LEFT JOIN SL ON tbl_Customer.CustomerID = SL.CustomerNumber) LEFT JOIN GL ON tbl_Customer.CustomerID = GL.CustomerNumber
GROUP BY tbl_Customer.CustomerID, tbl_Customer.CustomerName)
WHERE [Last Import] Is Null or DateAdd("yyyy", 3, [Last Import]) < Now()
ORDER BY [Last Import] Desc;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem with the initial query is that, for no imports (which will happen for "no order" customers) the condition

```
    DateAdd("yyyy", 3, ImportDate) < Now()
--> DateAdd("yyyy", 3, NULL) < Now()
--> NULL < Now()
--> NULL (or not true)
```

is not true. A simple fix is to add a guard

```
([Table1].[ImportDate] IS NULL
 OR DateAdd("yyyy", 3, [Table1].[ImportDate]) < Now())
```

around such expressions or to coalesce the NULL value before using it.

The ordering will also be wrong, as that means order by one value and *then* the other, not "by the greater of both" values. Compare with

```
ORDER BY
IIF(Table1.ImportDate > Table2.ImportDate, Table1.ImportDate, Table2.ImportDate)
```

---

However, I would use a LEFT JOIN on customers/orders, GROUP BY with a MAX on the order dates. Then you can use *that* result (as a derived subquery) to complete the query asked fairly trivially.

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerID
  , MAX(o.ImportDate) as lastImport
FROM tbl_Customer as c
-- The UNION is to simply "normalize" to a single table.
-- (Also, shouldn't the join be on a customer "ID"?)
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT CustomerName, ImportDate from Table1
        UNION
        SELECT CustomerName, ImportDate from Table2) as o
    ON c.CustomerName = o.CustomerName
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```

Then,

```
SELECT s.CustomerID
FROM (thatSubQuery) as s
WHERE
    -- no orders
    s.lastImport IS NULL
    -- only old orders
 OR DateAdd("yyyy", 3, s.lastImport) < Now()
ORDER BY s.lastImport
```

(YMMV with MS Access, this will work in a "real" database ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I put my resulting code with the help of yours in my OP comments.... I would format it if I could =/

Comment: @user2296381 I'm glad it's working! You can edit your original question as well, which is *sometimes* useful to codify the answer/solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tbl_Customer.CustomerID, 
    tbl_Customer.CustomerName, 
    Table1.ImportDate, 
    Table2.ImportDate
FROM (tbl_Customer 
LEFT JOIN Table1 
    ON tbl_Customer.CustomerName = Table1.CustomerName) 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
    ON tbl_Customer.CustomerName = Table2.CustomerName
WHERE DateAdd("yyyy",3,[Table2].[ImportDate]) < Now() 
AND DateAdd("yyyy",3,[Table1].[ImportDate]) < Now() 
AND tbl_Customer.CustomerID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        tbl_Customer.CustomerID, 
    FROM (tbl_Customer 
    LEFT JOIN Table1 
        ON tbl_Customer.CustomerName = Table1.CustomerName) 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 
        ON tbl_Customer.CustomerName = Table2.CustomerName
    WHERE DateAdd("yyyy",3,[Table2].[ImportDate]) >= Now() 
    AND DateAdd("yyyy",3,[Table1].[ImportDate]) >= Now() 
)
ORDER BY Table1.ImportDate DESC , Table2.ImportDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can infer from your query about your data structure, I think you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @CutOff DateTime
SET @CutOff = DATEADD(y, -3 GETDATE())

SELECT tbl_Customer.CustomerID, tbl_Customer.CustomerName
WHERE (CustomerName IN 
    (SELECT CustomerName FROM Table1 WHERE ImportDate < @CutOff))
    OR 
    (CustomerName IN 
    (SELECT CustomerName FROM Table2 WHERE ImportDate < @CutOff)))
    AND CustomerName NOT IN
    (SELECT CustomerName FROM Table1 WHERE ImportDate > @CutOff)
    AND CustomerName NOT IN
    (SELECT CustomerName FROM Table2 WHERE ImportDate > @CutOff)
```